# Spring Boot Elasticsearch and @JsonProperty

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, jackson

After migrating an app from Spring Boot 2.06 to 2.1.9, all properties marked with @JsonProperty *stopped* being indexed. Since they are not being indexed using properties's names it looks like Spring Data ES is using annotations to create the data sent to ES but the schema created is not.

I've read somewhere @JsonProperty are not supported after Spring Data ES 6.2 (or something) but, if that's the case, how should I do now to index these fields using a different name?

I also noticed newer versions enable @Field to set the name but it's not the case in SB 2.1.9 and, besides that, I also have some get methods marked with @JsonProperty.

Is it really expected to stop working? If so, what's the approach now? If not, What should I check to fix it?